# p:ConfirmDialog don't close p:dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Well, i have a p:confirmDialog that close p:dialog, but when i try to close p:dialog, that's don't works.

This is my p:confirmDialog code:

```
<p:confirmDialog id="confirmCancelar" message="Deseja cancelar ?" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade"
                header="Cancelar" severity="alert" widgetVar="confirmCancelar" appendToBody="true">
                <p:commandButton value="Sim" update="messages"
                    oncomplete="confirmCancelar.hide()"
                    actionListener="#{dentistaMB.cancelar}" type="button" />
                <p:commandButton value="Não" update="messages"
                    onclick="confirmCancelar.hide()" type="button" />
            </p:confirmDialog>
```

And my actionListener is:

```
public void cancelar(ActionEvent event){
        dentista.setPessoaFisica(new PessoaFisica());
        dentista.getPessoaFisica().setSexo(new Sexo());
        dentista.getPessoaFisica().setEstadoCivil(new EstadoCivil());
        dentista.getPessoaFisica().setSituacao(new SituacaoPessoa());
        dentista.getPessoaFisica().setUf(new Uf());
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("dialogCadastrar.hide()");
        addInfoMessage("Cancelado com sucesso");
    }
```

When i click "Não" button, the p:ConfirmDialog hides normal, but when i clicked "Sim" button the actionListener is not called, i tried debug the actionListener cancelar and it's never called.

**EDIT 1**

Guys, i changed my code p:confirmDialog (code bellow) but now the p:dialog is closed normaly, but p:ConfirmDialog continue in the screen.

```
<p:confirmDialog id="confirmCancelar" 
                 message="Deseja cancelar ?"
                 showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" header="Cancelar"
                 severity="alert" widgetVar="confirmCancelar" 
                 appendToBody="true">
    <p:commandButton value="Sim" oncomplete="confirmCancelar.hide()"
                     action="#{dentistaMB.cancelar}"
                     update=":formAlterar" />
    <p:commandButton value="Não" onclick="confirmCancelar.hide()"
                     type="button" />
</p:confirmDialog>
```

Comment: What you mean with "hardcode the listener value" ?, i didn't understand.

Comment: Try to remove `appendToBody="true"` from the dialog.

Comment: I removed the a 'appendToBody="true"' and the p:confirmDialog don't close itself and nor p:dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `type="button"` from `"Sim" commandButton`. Since `onComplete` won't be called when the type is button. Generally `onComplete` is related to ajax call.

Comment: I removed the type="button" but the problem continues, the actionListener "cancelar" is not called.

Comment: Some solution for that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need ay special case try to change oncomplete to onclick. It help in my case.

Comment: Well, i think the "oncomplete" event is executed after all process in button is finalized: ActionListener and Click button, for instance. And "onclick" event is the first process to be triggered. 
Think about that, i think that if i use "onclick" instead "oncomplete" the event to "hide" the confirmCancelar will be call early, before actionListener

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `action` (in your case, `action="#{dentistaMB.cancelar}"`), I think it doesn’t necessary to pass an event as a parameter to method "cancelar". It could be the reason by which your actionListener "cancelar" is not called.

You can try to put:`public void cancelar()` instead of `public void cancelar(ActionEvent event)`.

If you have to pass an event, I think you should use **actionListener** instead of **action**.
That is, `actionListener="#{dentistaMB.cancelar}"`